# Magnetic field a distance z away from the center of a current-carrying (counter-clockwise) loop?

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors, coordinate-systems

I know the answer to be

[image]

But I'm not exactly sure how to construct the vector $\mathrm{d}L$ to in turn utilize Biot-Savart's law to solve the problem.

[image]

Intuitively it seems if we take a point along the circle $(R\cosѲ, R\sinѲ, 0)$ and consider another point $(R\cos(Ѳ+\mathrm dѲ), R\sin(Ѳ + \mathrm dѲ), 0)$ as $\mathrm dѲ \to 0$ that subtracting the two should give us $\mathrm dL$. But since that's just the definition of the derivative, we arrive at
$$\mathrm dL = (-R\sinѲ, R\cosѲ, 0).$$
But this expression seems nonsensical: we have an infinitesimal vector = a vector with norm $R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for $d\vec L$ left out a factor of $d\theta$. For example, the correct Taylor expansions are

$$\cos{(\theta+d\theta)}\approx\cos\theta-d\theta\sin\theta$$

and

$$\sin{(\theta+d\theta)}\approx\sin\theta+d\theta\cos\theta.$$

The result is thus

$$d\vec L=R\,d\theta\,(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta,0).$$

By the way, this result can be written in the form

$$d\vec L=R\,d\theta\,\hat\theta.$$

This should look intuitive: Its magnitude is $R\,d\theta$, the length of an infinitesimal arc along the circle, and its direction is $\hat\theta$, along (tangent to) the circle.